# ActiveMQ query: How to start

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, activemq-classic

I am starting ActiveMQ process through Java code like this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(activeMQHome + "run_activemq.sh",
                                       logDirectory,
                                       activeMQHome,
                                       brokerPath);
pb.start();
```

- `logDirectory`: log location
- `activeMQHome`: `/Common/thirdParty/apache-activemq-5.3.0/bin/`
- `brokerPath`: brokerPath location

Now I have to start this process thorugh command line. Or to be more specific, I have to start it through `/etc/inittab` so that it can start automatically.

What entry should I give? I can start it by `./run_activemq.sh` but how will I give `logDirectory` and `brokerPath`?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is need to start AMQ process through Java code. ActiveMQ already comes with start/stop script in its `$ACTIVEMQ_HOME/bin` directory and that you can very well put in `/etc/inittab` to start at system startup. Log Directory and other settings are configured in `$ACTIVEMQ_HOME/conf/activemq.xml` file.